# configurable products not change stock on child select. Is it defaut behavour?

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, stock-status

Is it the default behavour of magento 2.3 when we select a child product to not refresh the stock as the price? Is it something known to solve this issue? 
or, any good extension for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime products require reindex to done, mostly when cron is not setup

Comment: It is no change on select. The configurable product show in stock and when the visitor select a child product which is out of stock the message is not updated like the price